# SQLite3 Studio - Error "unable to resolve database."

Tags: sqlite

I have a database created using SQLite Studio. The database is located in a folder on the same PC as SQLite Studio. Now when I attempt to open the database in SQLite Studio I get the error "unable to resolve database." I don't know what is causing this or how to fix it. The database remains where I created it, and I have linked a table to an Access application on the same machine where it continues to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled/reinstalled SQLite Studio and that cleared up the problem. No idea of the original cause.